# react native android keyboard empty space

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

I am trying to fix a problem we are having with the keyboard on android. Due to react-native-gifted-chat, we have to use `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` instead of `adjustPan`. The problem is, that the chat breaks without `adjustResize` and all the other stuff (e.g. some textfields in a form) break without `adjustPan`. I also tried `adjustResize|adjustPan`, `adjustPan|adjustResize` and tried to use `KeyboardAvoidingView` on the Form components, but nothing seems to work. Here is how it looks like when using `adjustResize` without any `KeyboardAvoidingView`. It creates some not-clickable grey area above the keyboard. Note that there is no way around `adjustResize` due to the chat...

Thanks in advance!

[image: The form Screen]
[image: When clicking a textinput]

Answer (score 1):

For anyone struggling with the same:

The package [react-native-set-soft-input-mode](https://github.com/MR03web/react-native-set-soft-input-mode) allows you to change the softInputMode, e.g. for the chat, the following works fine:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      SoftInputMode.set(SoftInputMode.ADJUST_RESIZE);
    }
    return () => {
      if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
        SoftInputMode.set(SoftInputMode.ADJUST_PAN);
      }
    };
  }, []);
```